# How to get TSX stock prices from Morningstar using Pandas Datareader (small-cap stock)?

Tags: finance, google-finance, stockquotes, pandas-datareader

Since using Google/Yahoo finance gives errors, I'm using Morningstar to get stock data in a dataframe. It works well with common NYSE/NASDAQ stock but is there a prefix/suffix to specify a stock is from the TSX (or other exchange)?

import pandas_datareader.data as web
CLQ_DataFrame = web.Datareader('CLQ', 'morningstar', time, time)

Works easily for AAPL (NASDAQ), MSFT (NYSE), FM (TSX) but CLQ is a very small company and executing this line basically does nothing, not even an error shows up.